# How to safely remove item from a vector?

Tags: vector, rust

Let's say I have this vector:

```
let mut v = vec![1,2,3];
```

And I want to remove some item from it:

```
v.remove(3);
```

It panics. How can I catch/gracefully handle that panic? I tried to use `panic::catch_unwind` but it doesn't seem to work with vectors (`std::vec::Vec<i32> may not be safely transferred across an unwind boundary`). Should I manually check if item exists at an index before removing it?

Comment: Most languages require/use “safety” checks; where violation of API is a coding error.

Comment: @user2864740 I am sorry I didn't understand... By safety check do you mean manually checking if item exists?

Comment: By checking if the INDEX IS IN RANGE. Nothing about a particular item existing.. Many languages will throw exceptions (panics, random crashes, eg.) when such invalid request is made to a collection. The problem was in the usage of the API, which is clearly documented: https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/vec/struct.Vec.html

Comment: @user2864740 I meant that, but conveyed badly, sorry. Yep it seems it's the only way (it's just so unidiomatic in Rust).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In general, vector and slice methods consider it a programming error if they receive an index that is out of range, and the convention in Rust is to panic for programming errors. If your code panics, you generally need to fix the code to uphold the invariant that was disregarded.

Some of the slice methods have variants that don't panic for invalid indices. One example is the indexing operator `[index]`, which panics for and out-of-bounds index, and the `get()` method, which returns `None` if the index is out of bounds.

The `remove()` method does not have an equivalent that does not panic. You should check the index manually before passing it in:

```
if (index < v.len()) {
    v.remove(index);
} else {
    // Handle error
}
```

In real applications, this should rarely be necessary, though. The code that generates the index to be deleted can usually be written in a way that it will only yield in-bounds indices.

Comment: "in Rust is to panic for programming errors" what is programming errors to you. For me you can panic only for unrecoverable error, not just errors, that the case of remove cause there is no object to remove so can't return it.

Comment: @Stargateur for more interactive applications, I really wouldn't want my server to go down with a hard panic just because user who tried to login didn't actually exist :)

Panicking should never be the way for anything logic oriented. Panics are for "hard/impossible to detect at compile time things" (for example what machine it will run on, you could be cross compiling and your user might not have AVX instructions, now that's a good excuse to panic, probably) and similar "actually irrecoverable" errors. Vec bounds cannot be checked at compile time, so we deal with runtime. For dev only.